# How to do flex row that wraps text but not stretch its background beyond shorter text?

Tags: react-native

I have following component that displays avatar and comment in the same row:

```
const CommentItem = ({avatar, message}) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10}}>
            <Image source={{uri: avatar}} resizeMode='cover' style={{width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 20, marginRight: 14}}/>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(50, 55, 61)', borderRadius: 15, paddingHorizontal: 14, paddingVertical: 8}}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 14}}>{message}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

When the component is being displayed, the text overflows off the screen like following image:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Rto.png)

So I tried adding `flex: 1` to line 5 (the one with `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`). Now the text is wrapped nicely, but for shorter texts the background get stretched to fill the screen width as shown in this picture: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kByJ.png).

Is there a way to keep the background fit the text while doing text wrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it dynamic by using `maxWidth` property in the `view`.

Example

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10}}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Rto.png'}} resizeMode='cover' style={{width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 20, marginRight: 14}}/>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(50, 55, 61)', borderRadius: 15, paddingHorizontal: 14, paddingVertical: 8, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10, maxWidth: width - 64}}> // -64 is due to Image Width: 40 + marginRight: 10 + 10 For your convenience
                            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 14}}>{' sadsaddaasdasdasdasdasd '}</Text>
                        </View>
                </View>

            </View>
```

where width = Your Screen Width

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window')
```